Running dbt is giving an error that the relation does not exist
I'm trying to run dbt in a Docker container alongside a PostgreSQL database in another container.
This is the error that I'm receiving when I run docker compose up.
Database Error in model anime (models/example/anime.sql)
relation "public.anime" does not exist
SELECT * FROM "database"."public"."anime"

My first thought was that the table didn't exist, or that it was not in the public schema, but I accessed the database container after docker compose up, and executed SELECT * FROM "database"."public"."anime" successfully.
Next, I thought the dbt service was executing the SQL command before my database container finished, but I do have depends_on in my Docker Compose file.
What I'm thinking is that the dbt service is not accessing the correct database, but I'm not sure how to check that.
Here are the services. dbt_service is trying to interact with destination_database_service.
services:
  destination_database_service:
    image: postgres:15.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: database
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - etl_network

  etl_script_service:
    build: ./scripts
    depends_on:
      - source_database_service
      - destination_database_service
    networks:
      - etl_network

  dbt_service:
    image: ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-postgres:latest
    command: [ "run", "--profiles-dir", "/root", "--project-dir", "/dbt" ]
    depends_on:
      - etl_script_service
    environment:
      DBT_PROFILE: series_analytics
      DBT_TARGET: dev
    networks:
      - etl_network
    volumes:
      - ./series_analytics:/dbt
      - ~/.dbt:/root

networks:
  etl_network:
    driver: bridge

Here is profiles.yml.
series_analytics:
  outputs:
    dev:
      dbname: database
      host: destination_database_service
      pass: password
      port: 5432
      schema: public
      threads: 1
      type: postgres
      user: user
  target: dev

Here is sources.yml.
version: 2

sources:
  - name: database
    description: "Data from anime table"
    database: database
    schema: public
    tables:
      - name: anime
        description: "A list of anime series"

Here is anime.sql.
SELECT * FROM {{ source('database', 'anime') }}


Remove "database" from your SQL statement: SELECT * FROM "public"."anime"

@FrankHeikens I believe that SQL statement is automatically generated by dbt when I run docker compose up. I've tried replacing all instances of database in my project, assuming the errors would be the same except for the replaced word, but the errors are different.
